# Password Strength Calculator

Tags: passwords, winrar, brute-force

I'd like to know how much time does a password cracker would take to break my password that has setup on `.rar` archive.

For Example- If my password has a length of 13 characters which has:

- 4 Letters (Lowercase + Uppercase)
- 9 Digits

Can you calculate its strength i.e how much time would it take to break or can you even crack a `.rar` archive file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine the entropy of a password](http://superuser.com/questions/268659/how-to-determine-the-entropy-of-a-password)

Comment: Jeff Atwood has an interesting article about passwords: [Cutting the gordian knot of web identity](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/09/cutting-the-gordian-knot-of-web-identity.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great way to see how secure it is:

http://www.passwordmeter.com/

This will tell you (around about) how much it would take for someone to bruteforce it:

http://lastbit.com/pswcalc.asp

Comment: [Here's](http://i54.tinypic.com/r8fh44.png) how I calculated, It seems impossible! If that's true, I'm in good.

Comment: Yeah that should be a good password. Keep in mind that those stats are probably based on a home computer. The NSA and some serious hackers would have botnets and supercomputers to do the dirty work, it might be possible. Then again, they probably don't care about your password :)